# Can't access parent node of an element via DOM

Tags: php, dom

I've got a table with 6 columns, and within the first column, there's a `div` with some info I don't need. So, I want to delete all the `divs`, but I keep getting an `Trying to get property of non-object` **error**. Here's the code:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html); //I've acquired this page via curl
$tbl = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(4); //The fourth table in the page
$div = $tbl->getElementsByTagName('div');
for ($i = 0; $i < $td->length-1; $i++){
   $chld = $div->item($i);
   $prnt = $chld->parentNode; <-- here I get the error
   $prnt->removeChild($chld);
}
```

Can you help me? Either by pointing the mistake I've made or giving me a hint at how to do it.

Comment: Don't you mean `$div->length` in your for loop?

Comment: Of course, you are right. I had a DOMNodeList with all tds in $td that was bigger than $div, so it was trying to iterate further. That was just dumb. It solved the problem, thanks!